# What equation precisely defines the epoch of recombination?

Tags: cosmology, temperature, space-expansion, cosmic-microwave-background

I understand that a very rough first estimate would be to assume this happens when the mean photon energy drops below the value required to photoionise hydrogen, namely when

\begin{equation} \label{eq1}
\begin{split}
T_{rec} & \approx \frac{Q}{2.7k}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
but this is a very crude estimate. What formula do I need to find the precise epoch?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33335/50583

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the current value for the temperature at which Recombination took place?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/439186/)